# Can Integrals "Double Count" the Area?

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry

Recently, I read the following formula:

Suppose we have a $d$ dimensional Cumulative Distribution Function $C()$ and we want to integrate this function over the range $a,b$. By simply evaluating $C(b) - C(a)$, we will be double counting certain areas. Therefore, we need to subtract them using the following formula:

$$C(b) - C(a) - \sum_{i=1}^{d} (-1)^i \sum_{1 \leq j_1 < ... < j_i \leq d} C(a_{j_1}, ..., a_{j_i}, b_{j_{i+1}}, ..., b_{j_d}) \geq 0$$

I am confused about the following:

- How exactly do we know that $C(b) - C(a)$ are double counting certain areas? Which areas are these? How can we be sure?
- And how exactly is $- \sum_{i=1}^{d} (-1)^i \sum_{1 \leq j_1 < ... < j_i \leq d} C(a_{j_1}, ..., a_{j_i}, b_{j_{i+1}}, ..., b_{j_d}) \geq 0$ identifying all the regions being double counted, and correctly removing them from the final calculation?

Can someone please help me understand this? I am trying to think of a concrete example of a specific CDF, so I physically see how certain areas are double counted and how this sum accounts for this double counting and remove's its influence.

Thanks!

**My own attempt to answer this question:**

- If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then the probability of either $A$ or $B$ occurring (denoted $A \cup B$) is the sum of their individual probabilities:

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B).$$

- If $A$ and $B$ are not independent, then the probability of either $A$ or $B$ occurring is the sum of their individual probabilities minus the probability of both $A$ and $B$ occurring (denoted $A \cap B$):

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B).$$

The term $P(A \cap B)$ is subtracted to correct for the double-counting

- In general, Cumulative Distribution Functions $F(X)$ and Probability Distribution Functions $f(x)$ have the following property:

$$ F(x) = P(X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) dt $$

$$ F(b) - F(a)  =  \int_{-\infty}^{b} f(t) dt - \int_{-\infty}^{a} f(t) dt $$

- In the case of random variables, if $X$ and $Y$ are completely  independent from each other, then:

$$\int_{a_1}^{b_1} \int_{a_2}^{b_2} C(x, y) \, dx \, dy = \int_{a_1}^{b_1} \int_{a_2}^{b_2} C_X(x)C_Y(y) \, dx \, dy.$$

We can see why this is only true for complete independence. As a counter example, consider a case where $X$ and $Y$ are perfectly positively correlated, i.e., $Y = X$. In this case, for any $x$ and $y$, $C(x, y)$ is 1 if $x \geq y$ and 0 otherwise. But $C_X(x)C_Y(y)$ is 1 only if both $x$ and $y$ are 1, and 0 otherwise. So, the equation $C(x, y) = C_X(x)C_Y(y)$ doesn't hold.

**I am still not sure how to mathematically show that when $X$ and $Y$ are not fully independent, double counting can occur ... and which areas exactly are being double counted.**  If I knew this, then I could simply subtract these double counted terms from the $C(b) - C(a)$ and treat it like a correction factor.

Comment: This looks like the [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) principle.

Comment: What is "a $d$ dimensional Cumulative Distribution Function $C()$" and what does it mean "to integrate this function over the range $a,b$"? Where did you find this formula?